# How to get GUID from javascript in an app part in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, app-part

I am making an app part in SharePoint 2013, the one where I can insert into a page like a web part. In the javascript code, for my purpose, I need a unique identifier for the instance of the app part I added to the page. For example, the GUID of a list is globally unique, this would be ideal to get. Is there a way I can get this from the javascript code?

Comment: Use Sp.Guid as suggested by Rob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an `SP.Guid` type in the JavaScript Client Object Model (in sp.runtime.js). To create a new Guid use `SP.Guid.newGuid`

**UPDATE:**

This update is based on further investigation done in response to the comments below.

Just like a "normal" web part, each instance of an app part has a web part id (which is unique). You can get the web part id in the code for the app part by following these steps.

Modify the Content element in the element manifest for the app part so that it adds the web part id to the query string. This can be done by adding `&amp;wpId=_WPID_` after `{StandardTokens}`.

```
<Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/HelloWorldClientWebPart.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;wpId=_WPID_" />
```

Then add the code in your app part page to extract the web part id from the query string.

```
var id = "";
var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var param = params[i].split("=");
    if (param[0] == "wpId") {
        id = decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

The id should be "g_" followed by a Guid. (e.g.  "g_4e04d031_0875_4bab_91ea_e13de4221ab8")

I found this information in this blog post on TechNet: [HOW TO: Detect an App Part in edit mode in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/02/04/how-to-detect-an-app-part-in-edit-mode-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Comment: So will this just retrieve the GUID of the app part instance? Also will it require an async task, i.e. ajax call, to get, or does it just come automatically with the app part?

Comment: The code above will create a new Guid. It's like Guid.NewGuid in .NET. It is a synchronous call..

Comment: But what if I use `SP.Guid`, doesn't that just retrieve the GUID? I don't want to create a new one, that would defeat the purpose I am doing.

Comment: First off, SP.Guid is a class, it's not a value. Second, when you say "retrieve the GUID", what Guid are you referring to?

Comment: I just wanted to get something that's unique to the instance of the app part from javascript without making an ajax call. For lists, they have a GUID like `%7B29A614E5%2D68F1%2D45A2%2D85EC%2DCA18CBAE10F1%7D` which would be the most ideal to get. Also for example, if I visit a page, I can get a lot of context information from javascript without an ajax call such as `_spPageContextInfo`. Basically I want something like that that gives me some unique ID for the app part instance.

Comment: I think I have a solution more inline with what you were looking for. I've updated my answer above with the new information.

Comment: Is `web part id` unique to the webpart or the instance of the webpart?

Comment: The instance of the web part.

Comment: I noticed you had a comment earlier about wanting to test something. Since the comment is not there anymore, does this mean that the above solution is actually the instance of the webpart and has no issues with the url?

Comment: There is no issue. The page that represents the user interface for an app part lives in the app. When SharePoint goes to render an app part it needs to make a request to get the contents of the page. The response from this request has the web part id as part of the query string. So, if there are three app parts on the page there are three requests, each request having its own unique web part id.