# How to get web part instance GUID from javascript from within the web part in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In sharepoint 2013, I have a content editor web part. I have javascript code in it. I want to get a GUID. I want to get the GUID of the **instance** of the web part. So if I had 2 content editor webparts they should have unique identifiers each. No other content editor web part (even on another page) should have that same GUID.

I was looking at the DOM explorer in dev tools, and see on the web part there is a tag with class `ms-WPBody` and attribute `webpartid="7722f3d5-e8da-4b3b-acc4-3bf3e6f9aba7"` (for example). It seems to be different per instance of this web part on the same page too.

If I put the javascript code in the web part (linked to a file option too). I am thinking of doing something like, using jquery's nearest function to get the closest parent `div.ws-WPBody` and then grabbing the webpartid value.

Is this an ok way, or is there any issues or better ways?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you want the ID from inside the web part, it is to ensure uniqueness in included client side script (since you might add the web part more than one time).

For this purpose, ID and ClientID works fine. If you need the GUID you could use string handling to remove the prefix.

```
protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    base.RenderContents(writer);

    writer.Write("WebPart ID: {0}<br/>", this.ID);
    writer.Write("WebPart ClientID: {0}<br/>", this.ClientID);
}
```

will render similar to this:

WebPart ID: g_4620e28f_2e09_49b9_9822_03bb3aa8b2b3 WebPart ClientID: ctl00_m_g_4620e28f_2e09_49b9_9822_03bb3aa8b2b3

```
WebPart1 myWebPart = (WebPart1)this.WebPartManager.FindControl(this.ID);
writer.Write("Webpart from WPM: ID: {0}", myWebPart.ID);
```

Webpart from WPM: ID: g_4620e28f_2e09_49b9_9822_03bb3aa8b2b3

Comment: But this is a javascript/client side only solution for an out of the box webpart, like a CEWP.

Comment: Hi omega, 
Please check this link https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163518/how-to-get-guid-from-javascript-in-an-app-part-in-sharepoint-2013/163524#163524

May be you will get an Idea